# how to change email list status for email address with REST API

Tags: marketing-cloud, rest-api, php

i am running into an issue with the REST API. I am able to subscribe a user to any list when they are new to the system using ->post(), but when a user is already in our system and unsubscribed from a specific list, I cannot update that user to make them re-subscribed to that specific list.

I have tried ->patch() and ->AddSubscriberToList. in both cases, i get a success message, but the subscribers status does not change.

When using ->patch() it will update user attributes, but not change the subscriber status for a list.

the code i am running. Am i missing something to change the subscriber status? you will see below that i have tried with and without subscriber key, makes no difference.

```
<?php
$subPatch = new ET_Subscriber();
$subPatch->authStub = $myclient;
$subPatch->props = array('EmailAddress' => $email); //'SubscriberKey' => $email
$subPatch->props['Attributes'] = array(
  //array('Name' => 'firstName', 'Value' => 'BILL'),
  array('Name' => 'Business_Unit', 'Value' => 'sandbox'), 
  array('Name' => 'email_source', 'Value' => 'lightbox-existing'),
);


$enabled_lists = array_filter(variable_get('aaa_email_collector_et_lists', array()));
$subPatch->props['Lists'] = array();
//$list_to_subscribe = array();
foreach ($enabled_lists as $list_id => $list_name) {
  $subPatch->props['Lists'][] = array('ID' => $list_id);
  //$list_to_subscribe[] = $list_id;

}

//$patchResult = $myclient->AddSubscriberToList($email, array('138704'));
$patchResult = $subPatch->patch();
?>
```

Comment: Where are you actually setting the status?  A list needs to have the status property = active for a subscriber.

Comment: @Timothy, I am not setting the status. I didnt see anywhere in the documentation on how to set the status. When originally adding someone, it automatically sets the status, so I'm not sure how to structure the array to pass status into the call.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would try using patch but add an attribute, name => 'status' value => 'active'.  Its a hidden attribute that defaults to active which is why it works on an add but not an update.

Comment: so, add that to the "lists" array? or add it to $subPatch->props?

Comment: add it to $subPatch->props['Attributes'] and let us know what happens.

Comment: I tried this in many different places, but no luck.

Comment: I was just working with something similar on this thread:(http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/43850/updating-subscribed-does-not-change-status) Why don't you have a look and see if that helps? Otherwise, post back here.

Comment: looks promising. ill check it out.

Comment: the link in the comment above is the solution to the problem.