# Updating Subscribed does not change status

Tags: marketing-cloud

When passing a subscriber.patch call to change the Status, I get a successful response but querying the email address at https://mc.exacttarget.com/cloud/ shows no change. I've tried setting the Status value in the Attributes as well but no luck.

EDIT: Added code snippet

```
module ExactTarget
  class Gateway
    class ExactTargetSubscriptionError < StandardError; end

    attr_reader :member_id

    def initialize(options = {})
      @client = FuelSDK::Client.new({'client' => { 'id' => options[:client_id], 'secret' => options[:secret] }})
      @member_id = options[:member_id]
    end

    def subscribe(email, attrs, list_ids)
      subscriber = build_subscriber(email, "Active", attrs, list_ids)
      response = perform_api_call(subscriber, "post")
      unless response.success?
        if response.subscriber_already_exists?
          response = update_subscriber(email, "Active", {"Status" => "Active"}, list_ids)
        end
      end
      response
    end

    def unsubscribe(email, list_ids)
      subscriber = build_subscriber(email, "Unsubscribed", {}, list_ids)
      response = perform_api_call(subscriber, "patch")
      response.success?
    end

    def update_subscriber(email, status, attrs, list_ids)
      subscriber = build_subscriber(email, status, attrs, list_ids)
      response = perform_api_call(subscriber, "patch")
      response.success?
    end

   private

   def build_subscriber(email, status, attrs, list_ids)
     subscriber = FuelSDK::Subscriber.new
     subscriber.authStub = @client
     subscriber.props = {
       "EmailAddress" => email,
       "SubscriberKey" => email,
       "Status" => status,
       "Attributes" => build_attributes(attrs),
       "Lists" => build_lists(list_ids)
     }
     subscriber
   end

   def build_attributes(attrs)
     attributes = [{ "Name" => "ChannelMemberID", "Value" => member_id }]
     attrs.each do |key, value|
       attributes.push({ "Name" => key, "Value" => value })
     end
     attributes
   end

   def build_lists(list_ids)
     list_ids.map { |list| {"ID" => list } }
   end

   def perform_api_call(subscriber, method)
     begin
       results = subscriber.send(method.to_sym)
       response = Response.new(results)
       #unless results.success?
       #  raise ExactTargetSubscriptionError, results.status
       #end
       response
     end
   end
 end
```

end

Comment: Please paste your code and we'll have a look.

Comment: Added code snippet

Comment: Just to make sure I understand... it NEVER works in your code.    You cannot make a status change, neither from active -> unsubscribed nor from unsubscribed -> active.  Is this the correct understanding?

Comment: Hey Timothy, I can subscribe a new user and then unsubscribe them. But once they are unsubscribed I can not change their Status to Active in order to re-subscribe them.

Comment: A thought: I do not believe you can set anyone to an active a list if they are currently unsubscribed in the All Subscribers list.  So, you would want to do that first before looping through the rest.

Comment: It's correctly changing the status in the All Subscriber's list. But for a specific list it doesn't seem to change the status.

Comment: And that happens first right?  Before the other lists are touched?

Comment: The first call to subscribe to a list works, unsubscribe to that list works. All calls to subscribe again to that list by changing the status to active does not work. I also tried two calls where the first would simply set the status to active on the All Subscribers list then set the status to active for the specific list. This did not work.

Comment: Next thing: try using ObjectID instead of ID.  Some objects rely on ID for their key, some ObjectID

Comment: Using ObjectID instead of ID returned an error in the response, List not Found.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is my hunch, after a weekend to sleep on it.  My guess is the status tied to the subscriber object is tied to the All Subs list ONLY.  That's why you can update that list but nothing else.  The LIST object is going to maintain who is subscribed to it.  I would start there.  See the SOAP version at http://help.exacttarget.com/en/technical_library/web_service_guide/objects/list/

Comment: Hey Timothy, you definitely sent me in the right direction. I was able to resolve the problem by setting the Status on the List property for a Subscriber. So for example "Lists" => [ { "ID" => 123456, "Status" => "Active" } ] will resubscribe a user to the list.

Comment: Resubscribing a user this way doesn't appear to work anymore. Has the API changed in some way?